# The grammar construction of "weiß überhaupt nicht"

Tags: sentence-structure, particle, modal-particle

> weiß überhaupt nicht

(There was no *Ich* in the original text, I assume because it is a continuation of a sentence which initially starts with “Ich weiß nicht”).

Is there an object in this sentence? Does *überhaupt* function as an object? If not, can you please tell me what is the grammatical function of *überhaupt* in this sentence?

The complete sentence is:

> Ich weiß nicht Ihre damals gewöhnliche Redensart, etwas Verdrängtes anzuerkennen., weiß überhaupt nicht, wie die Mama in den Traum kommt;

Comment: Welcome to German Language SE. Can you please clarify what you know and understood about the word *überhaupt* such that we know where to begin explaining?

Comment: Thank you, I don't read German as such, but it is an extract from the following sentence in one of Freud's articles - Thank you, it is in fact from a text by Freud, and the complete sentence is - Ich weiß nicht Ihre damals gewöhnliche Redensart, etwas Verdrängtes
anzuerkennen., weiß überhaupt nicht, wie die Mama in den Traum kommt;

Comment: Please [edit] that into your question. I wasn’t asking for context however, but your knowledge about the word *überhaupt,* e.g., do you know what it means and how it is typically used?

Comment: I don't know much...  I am not a German speaker unfortunately. I try to read the text, to understand a specific grammar issue relating to an analysis of the text I am working on, mostly with the English version.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm pretty sure your citation is wrong - Can you check again? My version of Freud's text has "ihre damals gewöhnlichen Redensart, etwas Verdrängtes anzuerkennen" as a footnote - So it is not part of the direct speech. I had to look this up first because it left me puzzled.

Your text really says

> »Ich weiß nicht Ihre damals gewöhnliche Redensart, etwas Verdrängtes anzuerkennen., weiß überhaupt nicht, wie die Mama in den Traum kommt; sie war doch damals nicht mit in L.«

So somehow the typesetting seems to be messed up there (can be seen by the  full stop, comma sequence at "anzuerkennen" as well). My text says

> "Ich weiß nicht (*), weiß überhaupt nicht, wie die Mama in den Traum kommt."
>
> (*) Ihre damals gewöhnliche Redensart, etwas Verdrängtes anzuerkennen.

this makes a lot more sense to me.

Dora's direct speech literally translates to

> "I don't know, don't know at all how mom got into this dream."

So the repetition "don't know at all" stresses and intensifies the "I don't know" of the first part. *Überhaupt* means "at all" in this as in most contexts.

Comment: I was using the following text -http://www.psychanalyse.lu/Freud/FreudDora.pdf

Comment: @Igarath No wonder you got problems translating it. The direct speech of Dora in that text is garbled up with Freud*s footnote.